# cordovaプラグインのアプリ内課金の処理をAngularjsで行いたい

Tags: monaca, html, onsen-ui, angularjs, アプリ内課金

お世話になります。開発環境はMonacaクラウドでアプリを開発しています。無料版は広告あり、アプリ内課金によって広告を非表示にしたいと考えています。

そこでアプリ内課金の処理を[cordova-plugin-inapppurchase](https://github.com/j3k0/cordova-plugin-purchase) によって実装しました。こちらは問題なく動きました。（※コメントアウトされている処理が当該部分です。）

ただ、広告表示のフラグや価格表示などをAngularjsの$scopeによって制御したいと思い、[ng-storekit](https://github.com/AlexDisler/ng-storekit)をインストールしました。説明に従いコードを記述しましたが、カスタムビルドしても処理自体が走りません。

目標はAngularjsで製品の価格を取得することです。
直すべき部分をご指摘いただければ幸いです。

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no">
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src * data:; style-src * 'unsafe-inline'; script-src * 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'">
    <script src="components/loader.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="components/loader.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
    <script src="js/ng-storekit.js"></script>   
    <script>
        var app = ons.bootstrap(['ngStorekit']);
        ons.ready(function(){

// ---for Cordova Purchase Plugin 処理ここから---
//           if(monaca.isIOS && window.storekit) {
//                storekit.init({
//                    debug:    true,
//                    ready:    function() {
//                        storekit.load(["com.productid"], function (products, invalidIds) {
//                            alert("In-app purchases are ready to go");
//                        });
//                    },
//                    purchase: function(transactionId, productId, receipt) {
//                        if(productId === 'com.productid') {
//                            alert("Purchased com.productid id 1");
//                        }
//                    },
//                    restore:  function(transactionId, productId, transactionReceipt) {
//                        if(productId === 'com.productid') {
//                            alert("Restored product id 1 purchase")
//                        }
//                    },
//                    error:    function(errorCode, errorMessage) {
//                        alert("ERROR: " + errorMessage);
//                    }
//                });
//            }
// ---for Cordova Purchase Plugin 処理 ここまで---

// ---for ng-storekit 処理ここから---
            $storekit
                .setLogging(true)
                .load(['com.productid'])
                .then(function (products) {
                    console.log('products loaded');
                })
                .catch(function () {
                    console.log('no products loaded');
                });            
// ---for ng-storekit 処理ここまで---       

        });


        // コントローラ間でデータを共有するサービス
        app.factory('SharedStateService', function() {
            var sharedData = {};
            sharedData.data = {};

            // データを設定
            sharedData.set = function(data) {
                sharedData.data = angular.copy(data);
                window.localStorage.setItem('Data', JSON.stringify(data));
            };

            // データを返す
            sharedData.get = function() {
                return angular.copy(sharedData.data);
            };
            return sharedData;
        });

        // メイン画面 Controller
        app.controller('mainCtrl', function($scope, SharedStateService) {
            $scope.price = 0; //初期値
            $scope.showAd = true;//広告表示フラグ

            $scope.Data = JSON.parse(window.localStorage.getItem('Data'));
            if ($scope.Data == null || Object.keys($scope.Data).length == 0) {
                $scope.Data = {
                    taxMode: true,
                    taxValue: 0.08
                };                
            }
            SharedStateService.set($scope.Data)

            ons.ready(function() {
                myNavigator.on("prepop", function(e) {
                    if (e.leavePage.name == "setting.html") {
                        $scope.Data = SharedStateService.get();
                    }
                });
            });
        });

        // 設定画面 Controller
        app.controller('settingCtrl', function($scope, $storekit,SharedStateService) {
            $scope.Data = SharedStateService.get();
            $scope.saveStorage = function() {
                SharedStateService.set($scope.Data)
            }
            $scope.clear = function() {
                $scope.Data = {
                    taxMode: true,
                    taxValue: 0.08
                };
                SharedStateService.set($scope.Data);
                alert("初期化完了!");
            }

// ---for Cordova Purchase Plugin　処理ここから---
//
//            $scope.buy = function() {                
//                if(monaca.isIOS && window.storekit) {
//                    storekit.purchase("com.productid");
//                }
//            }
//         
//            $scope.restore = function() {
//                if(monaca.isIOS && window.storekit) {
//                    storekit.restore();
//                }
//            }
// ---for Cordova Purchase Plugin　処理ここまで---

// ---for ng-storekit 処理ここから---
            var products = $storekit.getProducts();
            products.forEach(function (product) {
                alert(product.productId);
                console.log(product.description);
                console.log(product.price);
            });

            $scope.buy = function() {
                $storekit.purchase('com.productid');
            }

            $scope.restore = function() {
                $storekit.restore();
            }


            // watch for purchases
            $storekit
                .watchPurchases()
                .then(function () {
                    // Not currently used
                }, function (error) {
                    // An error occured. Show a message to the user
                }, function (purchase) {
                    if (purchase.productId === 'com.productid') {
                        if (purchase.type === 'purchase') {
                            // Your product was purchased
                        } else if (purchase.type === 'restore') {
                            // Your product was restored
                        }
                        console.log(purchase.transactionId);
                        console.log(purchase.productId);
                        console.log(purchase.transactionReceipt);

                    }
                });
// ---for ng-storekit 処理ここまで---

        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <ons-navigator var="myNavigator" page="main.html">
    </ons-navigator> 
</body>

<style>
body{  
    margin: 0;  
    padding: 100px 0 50px 0;  
}  
* html body{  
    overflow: hidden;  
}   
div#footerArea {  
    position: fixed !important;  
    position: absolute;  
    bottom: 0;  
    left: 0;  
    width: 100%;  
    height: 50px;  
    background-color: #4E9ABE;  
    color: #fff;  
}  
* html div#contentsArea{  
    height: 100%;  
    overflow: auto;  
}  
.settings-header {
  font-weight: 500;
  font-size: 14px;
  opacity: 0.4;
  padding: 10px 0 0px 10px;
  margin-bottom: -4px;
}

.settings-list {
  margin-top: 10px;
}
</style>
</html>
```

main.html

```
<ons-page ng-controller="mainCtrl">
<ons-toolbar>
    <div class="left"><ons-toolbar-button ng-click="myNavigator.pushPage('setting.html')"><ons-icon icon="fa-cog"></div>                
    <div class="center">消費税額計算</div>
</ons-toolbar>         
<br />    
<div id="contentsArea"> 
    <div style="text-align: center">
        金額　
        <input type="number" class="text-input" placeholder="税抜価格" ng-model="price"　>            
        <span ng-show="Data.taxMode">
            <br/>
                ×
            <br/>
            消費税 {{Data.taxValue*100}}%
            <br/>
            <br/>
            　={{price * Data.taxValue}}
        </span>                　
        <span ng-show="!Data.taxMode">
            <br/>
            <br/>
            ={{price}}                    
        </span>  
    </div>
</div>
<span ng-show="showAd"><div id="footerArea">広告</div></span>
```

setting.html

```
<ons-page ng-controller="settingCtrl">
<ons-toolbar>
    <div class="left"><ons-back-button>Back</ons-back-button></div>
    <div class="center">設定</div>
</ons-toolbar>

<div class="settings-header">消費税</div>            
<div style="text-align: center">
    <ons-list modifier="inset" class="settings-list">
        <ons-list-item>
          消費税を使用する
          <ons-switch modifier="list-item" ng-model="Data.taxMode"  ng-checked="Data.taxMode" ng-change="saveStorage()"></ons-switch>
        </ons-list-item>

        <ons-list-item ng-show="Data.taxMode"　>              
            <input type="number" class="text-input" placeholder="消費税を小数点入力" 
            ng-model="Data.taxValue" ng-blur="saveStorage()" style="margin-top:5px;">    
        </ons-list-item>
    </ons-list>
    <br/>
    <ons-button ng-click="clear()" >設定を初期化</ons-button>
    <br/>
    <br/>
    <ons-button ng-click="buy()" >広告をはずす</ons-button>
    <br/>
    <br/>
    <ons-button ng-click="restore()" >購入を復元</ons-button>
</div>
```

画面イメージ
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

＜追記＞
上記の代わりに、ng-storekitの作者の方が提供している[cordova-plugin-inapppurchase](https://github.com/AlexDisler/cordova-plugin-inapppurchase)の[サンプル](https://github.com/AlexDisler/cordova-inapppurchases-app)を試してみました。しかしPurchaseで購入処理はうまくいくものの、その後エラーが表示されます。またRestoreでは必ず落ちてしまい、原因がわからない状況です。

Answer (score 1):

自己解決しました。
１．index.htmlのons.ready内の処理を設定画面のコントローラーに移動
２．アプリの価格を取得するために、ready関数の中でproduct情報から価格を取得し、$scopeに設定
これでいけました。

```
ready:    function() {
　storekit.load(["com.productid"], function (products, invalidIds) {  
    var p = products;
    for(var i = 0; i < p.length; i+=1){
        if(p[i].id == 'com.productid'){
            $scope.price = p[i].price;
        }
    }
　});　},
```